# Git - checked out a file from a previous commit, did I lose the uncommitted work I had?

Tags: git

I had changed a file a decent amount, and wanted to see what changed since the last commit. My changes were not commited.

I used git checkout /path/to/file and successfully grabbed the file from my last commit.

Is there any way to go back to the uncommited work I had added, or is that lost forever?

Thanks

Comment: Check your editor's undo history.

Comment: After I asked I actually hit undo and was able to get my changes back. Didn't think that would possible, but that saved me a bit of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you checkout a file, it overwrites the file meaning that it is gone.

In the future, use `git diff` to see what has changed. Using `git diff` with no arguments will show all changes from the directory you're in or you can do `git diff /path/to/file` for the diff of just that file.

Comment: And in order to retrieve a file at a specific commit, use: `git show 123abcd:path/to/file`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, yes, you have probably lost it forever.

You'll have to write that code again.

Next time, when you want to do something like this, you may use `git stash`. Type `git help stash` to see what it does. Or as @Lekensteyn suggested, `git show` may be even better.

Comment: Well, lesson learned. Wasn't a ton, but now I'll commit then checkout a file or use diff or show.

Comment: @Squadrons: Or `git stash`.

Comment: Yes - but stash would have stashed a bunch of my changes - I wanted to keep most changes but see the old file on my last commit.

Comment: @Squadrons Once you've view your change. You can use `git stash apply` to apply all your changes back.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say I think you've lost your uncommited work forever :-(

For a better explanation see
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things